# Symfony 4 with PHP 7.3 I get Composer update error

Tags: composer-php, php-7.3, symfony-4.3

I changed my Ubuntu Plesk PHP Version to 7.3.11 to update my Symfony project with composer.
I get the following Error:

```
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I tried to install:
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd
sudo apt-get install php7.3-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mbstring

Restart with:
sudo service apache2 restart

No change. In my Plesk admin, all the extensions are enabled.

But looks like not from Plesk coming. Comes from the php from server. If I run php --ini I get:

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post full composer output? right now I don't see any meaningful error in what you have posted.

Comment: @ janmyszhier, i found the solution. The extension -zip was missing. Now it runs.

Comment: ok, please either provide an answer to the topic and accept it or remove the question so it doesn't show up in "unanswered" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension -zip was missing